# Looking for "Edit own Blocks" permission?

Tags: blocks, users

It would be very useful for me to have something like "Edit own Blocks" permission.

As administrator (user 1) I created some blocks in a site. I also gave permission to create new blocks to other role users.

Then these user now can edit and delete my blocks. I need them to be able to create their own block but not to edit nor to delete mines.

I tried with the https://drupal.org/project/block_access modulen which does the job but it adds a lot configuration stuff in every block which I just see "too much" for what I need.

Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block are not content. They don't have an owner, revision and all that. But there is another way round. You can make some of content to be a blocks with [Nodeblock](https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) or one of [it's competitors](https://groups.drupal.org/node/93499):

> This module allows you to specify content type(s) as being a block. This allows the content managers of the site to edit the block text and title without having to access the block administration page. Users only need edit access to that node in order to edit it.

That way you can create content type Block, and apply node permissions to it. All of them, including "edit own block".

Comment: It's a a good idea, but after creating a Nodeblock content type node the user will need permission to manage the new block (automatically created by Nodeblock) so that this user can set the area where this block is going to be shown, to set the block title and so on. Then I have again the same problem. Am I right?

Comment: @chefnelone Block title will be the same as node's title. Placing them around would be a harder task, unless you want something like Dashboard. If so, use it. If you are talking about "public" areas, you can't add ability to place block in it without ability to move other ones as you will need order rebuilt. And you can't reliably allow adding blocks with limit of blocks in area and without ability to remove some. Now when we pretty much have "edit own" settled, you might want ask another question, elaborating more about area management.